# Installing squirrelmail on CentOs

Tags: php, linux, centos, squirrelmail

I am trying to install squirrelmail in CentOs 6.5 and I am getting the below error.

```
# yum install squirrelmail -y
.....
---> Package tmpwatch.x86_64 0:2.9.16-4.el6 will be installed                        
--> Running transaction check                                                        
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be installed                           
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5 for package: php-5.3.3
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5 for package: php-5.3.3-27
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be installed                  
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5 for package: php-mbstr
---> Package php-pear.noarch 1:1.9.4-4.el6 will be installed                         
--> Finished Dependency Resolution                                                   
Error: Package: php-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)                                  
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5                             
           Installed: php-common-5.4.27-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)                    
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.27-1.el6.remi                                
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)                          
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-26.el6                                     
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)                     
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5                                   
Error: Package: php-mbstring-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)                         
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5                             
           Installed: php-common-5.4.27-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)                    
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.27-1.el6.remi                                
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)                          
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-26.el6                                     
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)                     
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5                                   
Error: Package: php-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)                                  
           Requires: php-cli(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5                                
           Installed: php-cli-5.4.27-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)                       
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.27-1.el6.remi                                   
           Available: php-cli-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)                             
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.3.3-26.el6                                        
           Available: php-cli-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)                        
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5                                      
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem                        
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest                                 
[root@ioi ~]#
```

I don't understand why the error is appearing.

I have tried both using `--skip-broke` and `rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest` But it is not solving the problem. I have PHP-FPM php-common and php-cli running anyone knows how to fix this problem?

Comment: hi @iOi i'm having the same problem, did you manage to find the solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

I Faced the same error as you and I manage to solve it by downloading & installing Squirrelmail on CentOS 6 following the next steps :

```
1- yum -y update
// Downloading the file 
2- wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/squirrelmail/stable/1.4.22/squirrelmail-webmail-1.4.22.zip
// unzip the file
3- unzip squirrelmail-webmail-1.4.22.zip -d /var/www/html/
// copy this to your project main path, you can also make a vhost
4- mv /var/www/html/squirrelmail-webmail-1.4.22/ /home/www.mywebsite.com/public_html/squirrelmail
// Set the correct permissions
5- chown -R apache: /home/www.mywebsite.com/public_html/squirrelmail/
// Create the configuration file
6- cd /home/www.mywebsite.com/public_html/squirrelmail/config 
    cp -p config_default.php config.php
// example of minimum configuration that you will need
$domain = 'mywebsite.com';
$data_dir = '/home/www.mywebsite.com/public_html/squirrelmail/data/';
$attachment_dir = '/home/www.mywebsite.com/public_html/squirrelmail/attach/';
$smtpServerAddress = 'localhost';
$imapServerAddress = 'localhost';
```